# Inserting an NSString into NSBundle's pathForResource?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, nsstring, uiimage

This animates the UIImageView in the impactdrawarray:

```
if ( ((impact *) [impactarray objectAtIndex:iv]).animframe == 70){
   ((UIImageView *) [impactdrawarray objectAtIndex:iv]).image =
          [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
                         [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"explosionA71"
                                                         ofType:@"png"]];
}
if ( ((impact *) [impactarray objectAtIndex:iv]).animframe == 71){
       ((UIImageView *) [impactdrawarray objectAtIndex:iv]).image =
                       [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                        pathForResource:@"explosionA72"
                                                 ofType:@"png"]];
}
```

Nothing appears with this:

```
NSString *myString2 =
           [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A%d",
                     ((impact *) [impactarray objectAtIndex:iv]).animframe;

((UIImageView *) [impactdrawarray objectAtIndex:iv]).image =
                    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                     pathForResource:(@"explosion%d", myString2)
                                              ofType:@"png"]];
```

My reference for using NSString (example)

```
NSString *myString23 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%d", money];
moneylabel.text = myString23;
```

How can I use a variable in the file name? Is there a way to load an image in a resource folder by index? something like `imageByIndex:currentanimationframe`? I didn't see anything in the UIImage documentation.

Response to comments:

```
   NSString *myString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A%d", ((impact *) [impactarray objectAtIndex:iv]).animframe];
  ((UIImageView *) [impactdrawarray objectAtIndex:iv]).image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"explosion%d", myString2] ofType:@"png"]];
```

and

```
                NSString *imagename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A%d", ((impact *) [impactarray objectAtIndex:iv]).animframe];
                UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imagename];

                ((UIImageView *) [impactdrawarray objectAtIndex:iv]).image = myImage;
```

Both compile and run, but the image does not show.

Comment: What have you tried? Saying "it doesn't work" isn't particularly useful without some further explanation.

Comment: The two code blocks below "Response to comments" is what I've tried. Both compile and run but no image appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `+stringWithFormat:`, just as in your example:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"explosion%d", myString2] ofType:@"png"];
```

Comment: NSString *myString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A%d", ((impact *) [impactarray objectAtIndex:iv]).animframe];
    ((UIImageView *) [impactdrawarray objectAtIndex:iv]).image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"explosion%d", myString2] ofType:@"png"]];

Still nothing shows up (still compiles OK)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* imageName = [self dynamicallyCalculateImageNameUsingCrazyMath];
UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```